# Regex to detect non-Latin Characters

Tags: regex, email, security

In pursuit of locking down an email security system, I found this rule which claims to block an email with any 4 consecutive non-latin characters,

`[^[:ascii:]\p{Latin}\pCc\pCf\pM\pZ\pP\pS]{4}.`

Its been a few years since I've played with any regex but I like to think that I remember a decent amount.

My question and confusion is, why the use of the Unicode General Category codes? Ive found a decent list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:General_Category_(Unicode)) but its not terribly great at helping understand what each of these would be used for.

I appreciate any help you fine folks could provide on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the explanation below:

> [^ ->  Matches a single character not present in the list
>
> [:ascii:] -> any valid ascii character
>
> \p{Latin} -> matches any character in the latin script
>
> \pC -> matches invisible control characters and unused code points
>
> c -> matches literal character c
>
> \pC -> Already explained
>
> f -> matches literal character f
>
> \pM -> matches a character intended to be combined with another
>   character
>
> \pZ -> matches any kind of whitespace or invisible separator
>
> \pP -> matches any  punctuation character
>
> \pS -> matches any math symbols, currency signs, dingbats etc.
>
> {4} -> Exact 4 occurrence of previous range

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can say it better than the source: Unicode® Standard Annex #44
UNICODE CHARACTER DATABASE [General Category Values](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values):

> The General_Category property of a code point provides for the most general classification of that code point. It is usually determined based on the primary characteristic of the assigned character for that code point. For example, is the character a letter, a mark, a number, punctuation, or a symbol, and if so, of what type?
>
> …
>
> Many characters have multiple uses, and not all such cases can be captured entirely by the General_Category value. … The General_Category is simply the first-order, most usual categorization of a character.

As to why use them in the case of security concerns, it seems like a way of avoiding [Unicode Confusables](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp) for readers who use Latin scripts.

> Confusable characters are those that may be confused with others (in some common UI fonts), such as the Latin letter "o" and the Greek letter omicron "ο". Fonts make a difference: for example, the Hebrew character "ס" looks confusingly similar to "o" in some fonts (such as Arial Hebrew)

For example, a hyperlink could be constructed to bring readers to a website that the reader would not otherwise be willing to go to.